# Initialize list of strings with 2 strings

Tags: c#

I have a Class Library wich contains this...

```
public class DataLib
{
    public async static Task<List<String>> Data1()
    {
        string var1= String.Empty;
        string var2 = String.Empty;
        ...
        return ???;
    }   
}
```

It have to be an async because there is an http request inside.

1. I have no idea how to return a list of strings.
2. If I try it with one string I get this error by using this string:

   > An implicit conversion from type "System.Threading.Tasks.Task string>" in "string" is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would just return a variable of type List. IE:

```
public async static Task<List<String>> TagMonatJahr()
{
    string var1= String.Empty;
    string var2 = String.Empty;        
    return new List<String>{var1, var2};
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You want to instantiate a new instance of the list, add the strings to that instance, and return it, i.e.

```
var list = new List<string>
{
    var1,
    var2
};

return list;
```

Here I am making use of C#'s [Collection Initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) as a shorthand instead of calling `list.Add` multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) tend to have full description of class together with examples of use. Use it as first source of information about .NET classes.

```
public class DataLib
{
    public async static Task<List<string>> TagMonatJahr()
    {
        string var1= String.Empty;
        string var2 = String.Empty;
        List<string> list = new List<string>()
        list.Add(a); list.Add(b);
        return list;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want two items and no more, then you could use a [Tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)